# Why should I use an editor for Git commit messages?

Tags: git

I get the feeling almost everybody uses an editor (Vim, Notepad++, etc.) for the Git commit messages. Why?

I find typing `-m` and a couple of quotes is easy and provides a easy way to redo a commit (pressing up arrow). I guess it's easier to do multi-line commit messages in an editor, but I have a hard enough time convincing fellow co-workers to write *any* message!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You mentioned the most important thing - length. Commit messages should essentially *always* be multi-line. The only exceptions are trivial commits (e.g. "bumped version number to X.X.X") or merges with no conflicts (though even then, appending a shortlog isn't a bad idea). The average commit, as far as such a thing exists, should probably have a sentence or two beyond the subject; some could even have paragraphs. Just look at the [log of git.git](http://git.kernel.org/?p=git/git.git;a=log); it's pretty much guaranteed to be a good example of commit message style and length.

I realize that it may be hard to convince others to write good commit messages, but that doesn't mean you can't - and you will probably find it easier to use an editor to write them.

(I have exactly the same experience in my workplace. My coworkers are engineers first, programmers second, and version control users... third would be generous. But you can at least do *your* job right!)

Comment: Don't see the benefit.  Looked at your example 'log of git.git'  It is definitely wordy, but most of it seems redundant.  Of course I do not work on Git.

Comment: @Pat: There is definitely some redundancy, but "most"? I can read those commit messages and have a very good idea of what every single one means *without looking at the code*. Yes, the entire commit message is redundant if you assume that you already understand all of the code, and can read it instantly...

Comment: @Pat: I think I tried a little hard to argue in that comment. What this boils down to is the fact that documentation is a good idea. We can debate about exactly how much, but a commit represents a set of work, some explanation of that work is necessary, and for anything at all complex, the explanation is probably not 50 characters or less.

Answer (score 8):

A proper git commit message should almost always be multi-line.  From [the official git-commit discussion](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit.html#_discussion),

> Though not required, it's a good idea
>   to begin the commit message with a
>   single short (less than 50 character)
>   line summarizing the change, followed
>   by a blank line and then a more
>   thorough description. Tools that turn
>   commits into email, for example, use
>   the first line on the Subject: line
>   and the rest of the commit in the
>   body.

If you're having a hard time getting any commit messages, (talk to your sysadmin and/or) make sure that at least one of the GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment variable is set to something useful.

An option would be to create your own 'editor', which prompts for a short (<50 chars) description, and then a minimum number of characters or sentences.  This might not be well received, but that would depend on your position and the culture of your work environment.

Comment: People can always override environment variables, or use the editor to write a one-line message like they usually do. If you really want to try to enforce this, rather than just convince people it's in their own interests, the way to do it would be a hook. At the very least, print a loud warning when someone pushes a one-line commit message. If they push a dozen commits, all with one-line messages, I think you're entitled to make the push fail.

Comment: @Jefromi - If people are intentionally overriding environment variables to avoid following policy, then you've got a bigger issue on your hands!

Comment: Actually, it's kind of a moot point - the editor won't open at all if someone specifies a message with `git commit -m`. Not sure why I didn't realize that immediately. So, if people just want to write short messages, they'll just keep using `commit -m` like they always have, and there'll be no gain. People don't really think of it as avoiding policy - they think of it as avoiding the annoyance of extra steps, an editor, having to figure out something to write... It's a pretty big problem, yes, but assuming people aren't already writing good messages, it's a problem you have.

Comment: The vim syntax highlighting for a git commit message uses color to help you conform to this "50-character short summary, blank line, longer summary" standard.

Answer (score 7):

Some people have conventions, [such as the following](http://tbaggery.com/2008/04/19/a-note-about-git-commit-messages.html):

> Short (50 chars or less) summary of
>   changes
>
> More detailed explanatory text, if
>   necessary.  Wrap it to about 72
>   characters or so.  In some contexts,
>   the first line is treated as the
>   subject of an email and the rest of
>   the text as the body.  The blank line
>   separating the summary from the body
>   is critical (unless you omit the body
>   entirely); tools like rebase can get
>   confused if you run the two together.
>
> Write your commit message in the
>   present tense: "Fix bug" and not
>   "Fixed bug."  This convention matches
>   up with commit messages generated by
>   commands like git merge and git
>   revert.
>
> Further paragraphs come after blank
>   lines.
>
> - Bullet points are okay, too
>
> - Typically a hyphen or asterisk is used for the bullet, preceded by a
>   single space, with blank lines in
>   between, but conventions vary here
>
> - Use a hanging indent

Good luck doing that without using an editor.

Answer (score 2):

In an editor you can write longer messages, do formatting like justify to 80 columns, etc. Maybe you have a template for commit messages that you copy and paste. You can do these things in text editors.

Comment: You don't need to copy'n'paste template, as git supports commit message templates (and many editors supports templates too).

Answer (score 1):

I first began learning vim by setting it as my default editor for Mercurial; it forced me to at least know the basic commands if I wanted to get anything done. Now I use vim all the time.